# PL/SQL increment in a WHILE loop

Tags: plsql, while-loop, increment

I’m trying to calculate the total number of items that can be purchased with a given amount of money. To do this, I am trying to create a block with a WHILE loop to increment the item's cost until the dollar value ($100) is met, but can’t figure out how to calculate the loop correctly.

```
DECLARE
lv_totavail_num NUMBER(8,2) := 100;
lv_itemprice_num NUMBER(8,2);
lv_totamt_num NUMBER(8,2);
lv_loopnum_num NUMBER(8,2) := 0;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Starting Amount: ' || lv_totavail_num);
SELECT price
INTO lv_itemprice_num
FROM BB_PRODUCT
WHERE IDPRODUCT = 4;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Price: ' || lv_itemprice_num);
WHILE lv_totavail_num >= lv_itemprice_num LOOP
lv_totavail_num := lv_itemprice_num * lv_loopnum_num;
lv_loopnum_num := lv_loopnum_num + 1;
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of Items Purchased that can be purchased: ' || lv_loopnum_num);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Amount: '|| lv_loopnum_num * lv_itemprice_num);
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while has incorrect content. Use `lv_totamt_num` to calculate prices.
There are also other small things. Check the below:

```
DECLARE
lv_totavail_num NUMBER(8,2) := 100;
lv_itemprice_num NUMBER(8,2) := 0;
lv_totamt_num NUMBER(8,2) := 0;
lv_loopnum_num NUMBER(8,2) := 0;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Starting Amount: ' || lv_totavail_num);

SELECT price
INTO lv_itemprice_num
FROM BB_PRODUCT
WHERE IDPRODUCT = 4;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Price: ' || lv_itemprice_num);
WHILE lv_totavail_num >= lv_totamt_num LOOP
lv_loopnum_num := lv_loopnum_num + 1;
lv_totamt_num := lv_itemprice_num * lv_loopnum_num;

END LOOP;
lv_loopnum_num := lv_loopnum_num -1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of Items Purchased that can be purchased: ' ||lv_loopnum_num  );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Amount: '|| lv_loopnum_num * lv_itemprice_num);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you< I appreciate the help.